# Scalar Variable @AssetNumber

Tags: c#, sql, parameters

When i step through the code the parameter is being added, its just when the sql command is executed, it throws this error up

```
  public static DataTable GetPostings2(string AssetNumberV, string PeriodFromV, string PeriodToV)
    {
        DataTable dtGetPostings2;
        try
        {
            dtGetPostings2 = new DataTable("GetPostings");

            SqlParameter AssetNumber = new SqlParameter("@AssetNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar, 6);
            AssetNumber.Value = AssetNumberV;

            SqlParameter PeriodFrom = new SqlParameter("@PeriodFrom", SqlDbType.VarChar, 6);
            PeriodFrom.Value = PeriodFromV; 

            SqlParameter PeriodTo = new SqlParameter("@PeriodTo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 6);
            PeriodTo.Value = PeriodToV; 

            SqlCommand scGetPostings2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [POSTING] WHERE [ASSET_NO] = @AssetNumber And PERIOD >= @PeriodFrom AND PERIOD <= @PeriodTo ORDER by PERIOD, JOUR_REF, JOUR_LINE", DataAccess.AssetConnection);

            SqlDataAdapter sdaGetPostings2 = new SqlDataAdapter();
            sdaGetPostings2.SelectCommand = scGetPostings2;
            sdaGetPostings2.Fill(dtGetPostings2);

            return dtGetPostings2;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error Retriving Posting Details: Processed with this error:" + ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Throws up what error exactly? Can you post the complete exception (w/ stacktrace), please?

Comment: You don't add the parameters to the command object anywhere.

Comment: "Must declare the scalar variable" "@AssetNumber".

Comment: martin i have done [Asset_No] = @AssetNumber

Comment: sorry martin, i know were i have went wrong now, i will now at this to the command now cheers folks

Answer (score 3):

The code listed does not add the parameters to the [SqlCommand.Parameters collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx). For example:

```
SqlCommand scGetPostings2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [POSTING] WHERE [ASSET_NO] = @AssetNumber And PERIOD >= @PeriodFrom AND PERIOD <= @PeriodTo ORDER by PERIOD, JOUR_REF, JOUR_LINE", DataAccess.AssetConnection);
scGetPostings2.Parameters.Add(AssetNumber);
scGetPostings2.Parameters.Add(PeriodFrom );
scGetPostings2.Parameters.Add(PeriodTo );

// Code continues as above
SqlDataAdapter sdaGetPostings2 = new SqlDataAdapter();
// And so on
```